# Why can't we generate the output of a cellular automata at time step t without first generating all the preceding states

Tags: complexity-theory, cellular-automata

Why can't we generate the output of cellular automata at time step t without first generating all the preceding states? Why can we do this for some functions? What features of a function does it relate to? Is it about whether it can be graphed as a line or a curve? Why can't we come up with a function that takes in a cellular automata ruleset and a timestep t and gives us the output in constant time with respect to t?

Comment: Can you generate the output of cellular automata at time step t without first generating all the preceding states?

Comment: Because ["one of these rules is Turing-complete"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton). Wait, although I believe that logic/intuition is correct, I have not understood it fully yet.

Comment: You can try applying the time hierarchy theorem to get a time lower bound for specific Turing-complete rules.

Comment: You can do this for _some_ cellular automata. For example, try predicting the output of the [Wolfram elementary CA rules](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryCellularAutomaton.html) 204, 240, 254, 60 or 150 after $t$ steps. I think you'll be able to find some shortcuts...

Comment: "Why can't we come up with a function that takes in a cellular automata ruleset and a timestep t and gives us the output in constant time with respect to t?" Because, in constant time, you can't even read the value of $t$.

Comment: @DavidRicherby In order to not trivialize OP's question, I assumed the RAM model.